# Ошибка: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mysite'

Tags: python-3.x, django

Первый раз работаю с Django.
Сначала установила:

```
pip install Django
```

Потом создала проект:

```
django-admin startproject django_netology
```

Создала приложение:

```
./manage.py startapp app
```

В settings.py записала:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'app'
]
```

Пытаюсь запустить проект:

```
./manage.py runserver
```

И выходит вот такая ошибка:

```
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 15, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\kotel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\kotel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\kotel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 329, in run_from_argv
    connections.close_all()
  File "C:\Users\kotel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 220, in close_all
    for alias in self:
  File "C:\Users\kotel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 214, in __iter__
    return iter(self.databases)
  File "C:\Users\kotel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 37, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\kotel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 147, in databases
    self._databases = settings.DATABASES
  File "C:\Users\kotel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 57, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "C:\Users\kotel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 44, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "C:\Users\kotel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 107, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "C:\Users\kotel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 965, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mysite'
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что я делаю не так? И как исправить? Заранее благодарна за ответ.

Comment: Отправьте пожалуйста код файлов urls.py и views.py. Скорее всего, Вы в этих файлах либо неправильно импортировали модуль, либо этого модуля вообще не существует.

Comment: @Вантик Иванов, спасибо большое за комментарий. Я уже сама разобралась с этой ошибкой.

Comment: Изверг. Сама разобралась а ошибку не объяснила. Но, судя по всему, в данном случае ошибка по невнимательности и субъективно-ваша. Но все равно, хоть объясните, что пропустили

Comment: @FedotSoldier, я уж и сама забыла в чём конкретно я была неправа))) Нашла на youtube видео, как правильно настроить Django. Полностью повторила то, что показали и всё заработало! Проблема, конечно, в моей невнимательности